# Can I skip validations on state transitions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, state-machine

I'm currently using the [state_machine gem](https://github.com/pluginaweek/state_machine).

If I have the following state machine:

```
state_machine :status, do
  state :published, :deleted

  event :remove do
    transition published: :deleted
  end
end
```

When my object is not valid, any state transition fails:

```
post.valid? => false
post.remove! => 
  StateMachine::InvalidTransition: Cannot transition status via :remove from :published
```

I want to be able to transition without a validation check, similar to: `ActiveRecord#save(validate: false)`

Is there a good way to skip `ActiveRecord` validation during a state transition?

Comment: if validations depend on contexts, they should be moved to form objects

Comment: @apneadiving That concept is a bit new to me but really does look like the right solution. Although refactoring to that seems to be a bit more involved then I want right now. =X

Comment: I guess that you want to change status to `:deleted` when an object is invalid and you need to get rid of it. In such case you could update the status manually via `update_column`, it will not fire validations. However a good question is - how did the object ended up persisted (I assume) in invalid state in the first place?

Comment: @MichalSzyndel I think there were validations added over time, so records persisted in the past aren't always valid now based on the newest validation rules. (And thanks, I might use this solution, although it does forego some of the sexiness of using a state machine in the first place =P)

Comment: Yes, so if it's changing requirements problem I would suggest either get old records in line with validations or do it by hand.

Comment: @MichalSzyndel Agreed, although naturally there's a concern about massaging old data. In the end, I think there's still the question of whether I can implement this as a rule on a per-transition level.

Answer (score 0):

Given your comment that this problem is mainly about old records that are not up-to-date with current validations, I'd say you can do two things:

1. Update all records to conform with current model validations. This may be hard and will require time (and likely also adjusting validations and tests)
2. Update those records omitting validations (and not using state machine) with `Model.update_column state: 'deleted'` or `Model.where(_to_be_deleted_).update_all state: 'deleted'`